# 2 Errors That I Dont Know What

Tags: c#

I am coding on unity c# idk what the problem is.
Can Somebody please help mo on how to fix it?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;SceneManager;

public void Play() 
{
    SceneManager.loadScene(1);
}

public void Quit()
{
    Application.Quit();
}
```

Comment: You didn't show the errors?

Comment: Before asking anymore question, please take the time to read [ask] :)

Comment: 1) look at your error message 2) carefully read it 3) try to understand what it might mean 4) look at the line of code producing the error 5) when still not fixed, use a search engine and search for your error message

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say without the error but the line

```cs
using UnityEngine;SceneManager;
```

is wrong, it should be:

```cs
using UnityEngine.SceneManager;
```

Comment: Good answer, bad question. here have a + anyway

Comment: Adding to TheGeneral's comment, _[Stance on answering “bad” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281793/stance-on-answering-bad-questions)_ and _[Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)_.  Here is a +1 regardless.  Wishing you well